# Integrals over half-space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $R^n$.  If I have a function $g$ such that $\int_H  g = 0$ for all half-spaces $H$, is it necessarily true that $g$ is 0 $\mu$ almost everywhere?  I know this is true for the Lebesgue measure, which can be proved via Fourier analysis, but I don't know whether Fourier analysis applies for arbitrary measures.